# Dart/Retrofit - how to handle various reponses from the same endpoint?

Tags: flutter, dart, retrofit

Example definition:

```
 @POST('/{path}/endpoint')
  Future<Map<String, String>> apiCall(
    @Path('path') String path,
    @Body() MyRequest request,
  );
```

This is fine when json from server is `Map<String,String>`. But that's not always the case. Sometimes server returns additional map key, which is another `Map<String,String>`. How to handle it?

My first idea was to use dynamic/Object instead of String and check actual type after I get data, but I can't use `Future<Map<String, Object>>` or `Future<Map<String, dynamic>>`, because generated code will use `Object.fromJson()` or `dynamic.fromJson()`, which is wrong.

What is correct solution in this case?

Comment: can you add more example about the `server returns additional map key` (expected and unexpected response body)